# "Fatal error: Call to a member function setFormClass()"

Tags: 9, external-scripts

I am trying to load the node in an external script, and shows me the following error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setFormClass() in field_ui_entity_type_build()

The code causing the error is the following one.

```
define('DRUPAL_DIR', dirname(realpath(dirname(__FILE__))));
use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$autoloader = require_once DRUPAL_DIR . '/autoload.php';
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod', FALSE);
$kernel->boot();
$kernel->preHandle($request);

$nid = 123;
$node = Node::load($nid);
$node->set('field_number', 222);
$node->save();
```

Any help?

Comment: This code works fine, for me it was a problem with memcache, I just disabled and it started working again. Strange but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

The code shown in the question doesn't correctly bootstrap Drupal. An external script needs to do that, differently from a module. While loading the autoloader allows PHP to find the `Node` class, that isn't sufficient to bootstrap Drupal correctly.

I usually use the [authenticate.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21authorize.php/9.1.x) file as guideline for writing code for an external script file that needs to bootstrap Drupal.

```php
use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
use Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\RouteObjectInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

// Change the directory to the Drupal root.
// Edit the following line to make it point to the directory containing the autoload.php file.
chdir('.');
$autoloader = (require_once 'autoload.php');

try {
  $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
  $kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod');
  $kernel->boot();

  // A route is required for route matching.
  $request->attributes->set(RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_OBJECT, new Route('<none>'));
  $request->attributes->set(RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_NAME, '<none>');
  $kernel->preHandle($request);

  // Ensure our request includes the session if appropriate.
  if (PHP_SAPI !== 'cli') {
    $request->setSession($kernel->getContainer()->get('session'));
  }
} catch (HttpExceptionInterface $e) {
  $response = new Response('', $e->getStatusCode());
  $response->prepare($request)->send();
  exit;
}

\Drupal::moduleHandler()->addModule('system', 'core/modules/system');
\Drupal::moduleHandler()->addModule('node', 'core/modules/node');
\Drupal::moduleHandler()->load('system');
\Drupal::moduleHandler()->load('node');

$node = Node::load(123);
$node->set('field_number', 222);
$node->save();
```

Actually, [`$kernel->preHandle($request)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DrupalKernel.php/function/DrupalKernel%3A%3ApreHandle/9.1.x) should be sufficient to load all the modules, since it contains the following code.

```php
// Load all enabled modules.
$this->container->get('module_handler')->loadAll();
```

The code that explicitly loads the modules isn't necessary. At the same time, not explicitly loading the modules makes the code dependent from the installation profile, as the previous code line only loads the modules the installation profile enabled.

Comment: The code in the question is working fine for all other actions except node load.